# How to know number of rows deleted when I do commit in mySQL from Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have two `delete` operation on two different tables. After deleting I have know whether both of the queries executed. This is my code.

```
properties.load(inputStream);
String sql = properties.getProperty("deleteImageByImageID");
ps = DBConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, imageID);

sql = properties.getProperty("deleteAnnImageByImageID");
ps2 = DBConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps2.setString(1, imageID);


int count    = ps.executeUpdate();
count       += ps2.executeUpdate();
```

But now I did change in the code by adding

```
DBConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
....
DBConnection.commit();
```

Now how do I know whether both the statements were executed successfully (Both deletes happened)??

Comment: But you didn't comment out the commented out code, otherwise nothing would get deleted. The logic you have there for accumulating the count is stull valid.

Comment: Sigh. If those lines were commented out, there were no deletions, so the correct answer is zero. If they weren't, the correct answer is still given in `count,’ with or without the `commit().’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
ps = DBConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, imageID);

ps2 = DBConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps2.setString(1, imageID);

int count = ps.executeUpdate();
count += ps2.executeUpdate();

connection.commit();
```

The counts returned by the `executeUpdate()` calls are the number of rows that will be affected *when* the transaction commits.  If the transaction rolls back, then no rows will be affected.

> Now how do I know whether both the statements were executed successfully??

Depends what you mean by "executed successfully":

- If you mean, "without SQL errors" and the like, then you know that it has happened if there are no SQL exceptions in the prepare, set and execute statements.  If any of the SQL statements fails, the transaction won't be commit-able.
- If you mean that the changes were written safely to disk (or whatever), then you know that it has happened if the commit didn't throw an exception.
- If you mean that the changes were what you expected, then all of the above, AND the counts are what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly depending on the severity of the failure there could be an exception thrown, so you should make sure and use a try/catch - if it throws an exception you want to handle it.

Secondly, in your catch you will need to roll back the traction.

```
DbConnection.rollback();
```

Comment: I am using it inside try. And in catch I am doing rollback. So If no exception is caught, will it mean both rows are deleted successfully.